# Throw Exception when the String shape is illegal

Tags: java

Im doing something wrong with the Excetpion in my code because when a `String layout` such as:

```
..b.
bbb.     //<---Illegal

...
.x.
...      //<---Illegal

..r
.rr      //<---Illegal

.....
.y...
..y..
...y.    //<---Illegal
```

is passed into the method (only one layout can be passed at one time), **the method should throw an exception because  `String layouts` for shapes must have at least one filled block in each of `0th row`, `0th column`, `last row`, and `last column`**. The following `String layout`s are legal:

```
...e
..e.
e...

a...a
.....
.....
a....
```

My code only handles Exception when it sees the first and last charcters of the first line. Can smb please help me out with this method regarding `throwing Exception`? Thanks in advance!

```
public static Shape makeShape(String layout,char displayChar)
  {
      Shape result;
      int height = 0;
      int width = 0;
      Scanner data = new Scanner(layout);
      char[][] temp;
      while(data.hasNextLine())
      {
          String line = data.nextLine();
          height = line.length();
          width++;
      }
      temp = new char[height][width];

      Scanner data2 = new Scanner(layout);
      while(data2.hasNextLine())
      {
          String line2 = data2.nextLine();
          if(line2.charAt(0) == '.' && line2.charAt(width) == '.')
              throw new FitItException("Empty borders!");

        else {

            for (int r = 0; r < height; r++)
                for (int c = 0; c < width; c++) {
                    // System.out.println(line2.charAt(c));

                    if (temp[r][c] == '.') {
                        temp[r][c] = displayChar;
                    }
                    System.out.println(line2.charAt(temp[r][c]));

                    }
            }
      }
      result = new CreateShape(height, width, displayChar, layout);
      return result;
  }
```

Comment: Are you saying that each .... block is a layout, or the entire set of blocks including blank lines? Because what would mean that height (which is strangely the width of your string) is not uniform for all lines. Also in you nested for loop, you check for character == '.' but nothing is ever assigned to that char array.

Comment: Short answer: read the whole array and then do your check.  How can you tell whether there is a filled block in the last line, until you know that the line you've read is the last line?  How can you tell whether there is a filled block in the leftmost column, until you've read every line so that you can check the whole column?  You can't.

Comment: @ArneClaassen only a block is a layout.

Comment: @ajb, after reading the whole String, how can I check the last line's characters?

Comment: Split it on newlines to get each row as a string, and then convert it to a 2-D `char` array.

Comment: It looks like your intention is to use the `temp` array to hold the characters from the input, but you're not doing that at all.  If you set the array up correctly, then you can check it after the `while` loop is finished reading all the lines.  However, I'm not really sure if I understand your code right.  My main point is that you cannot do this check until the `while` loop is finished, but right now your code has too many other problems to say exactly how you should do the check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things not clear to me still, so I concentrated on parsing the layout into a two dimensional char array and checking for the constraints you specified. Hopefully that will let you adapt it to your exact needs:

```
public static char[][] parseShape(String layout, char displayChar) throws Exception {
    int height = 0;
    Scanner data = new Scanner(layout);
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

    // parse layout into an array of lines to determine dimensions
    while (data.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = data.nextLine();
        lines.add(line);
        height = line.length();
    }
    int width = lines.size();
    char[][] temp = new char[height][width];
    Boolean row0 = false;
    Boolean col0 = false;
    Boolean rowLast = false;
    Boolean colLast = false;

    // parse array of lines in char array and check for constraints
    for (int w = 0; w < width; w++) {
        String line = lines.get(w);
        for (int h = 0; h < height; h++) {
            char c = line.charAt(h);
            if (c == displayChar) {

                // we are looking at the display characters,
                // check if we're in any of rows of columns that matter
                if (h == 0)
                    row0 = true;
                if (w == 0)
                    col0 = true;
                if (h == height - 1)
                    rowLast = true;
                if (w == width - 1)
                    colLast = true;
            }
            temp[h][w] = c;
        }
    }

    // if any of the constraints are not true, the layout is invalid
    if(!row0) {
        throw new Exception("no block in Oth row");
    }
    if(!col0) {
        throw new Exception("no block in Oth column");
    }
    if(!rowLast) {
        throw new Exception("no block in last row");
    }
    if(!colLast) {
        throw new Exception("no block in last column");
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Basically we have to parse the entire layout and accumulate the constraints that are satisfied rather than checking for non-satisfaction. Only at the end will we know if they are not all satisfied.

Comment: +1; but just because the OP used "height" to mean "width" and vice versa, that doesn't mean it's a good idea . . .

Comment: I agree, and transposing it in my head was certainly tripping me up, but i wanted to stay as close to the source and just concentrate on the constraints checking

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach might be to use regular expressions.

Your requirements can be expressed as:

- at least one line must start with a non-`.`
- at least one line must end with a non-`.`
- the first line must contain at least one non-`.`
- the last line must contain at least one non-`.`

The patterns for these can be written as:

```
private static final LINE_STARTS_WITH_NON_DOT =
    Pattern.compile("^[^.]", Pattern.MULTILINE);
private static final LINE_ENDS_WITH_NON_DOT =
    Pattern.compile("[^.]$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
private static final FIRST_LINE_CONTAINS_NON_DOT =
    Pattern.compile("^\\.*[^.]");
private static final LAST_LINE_CONTAINS_NON_DOT =
    Pattern.compile("[^.]\\.*$");
```

To ensure that each pattern matches `layout`, you can write:

```
if (!LINE_STARTS_WITH_NON_DOT.matcher(layout).find()
    || !LINE_ENDS_WITH_NON_DOT.matcher(layout).find()
    || !FIRST_LINE_CONTAINS_NON_DOT.matcher(layout).find()
    || !LAST_LINE_CONTAINS_NON_DOT.matcher(layout).find()) {
    throw new FitItException("Empty borders!");
}
```

(Note: the above assumes that `layout` does *not* end with a newline. If it *does* end with a newline, then you'll need to change `LINE_ENDS_WITH_NON_DOT` to `Pattern.compile("[^.]\n")` and `LAST_LINE_CONTAINS_NON_DOT` to `Pattern.compile("[^.]\\.*\n$")`.)